# DAX: How to get distinct value from table based on multiple filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with personal information and among tchem I have:

```
returningCustomer [TRUE/FALSE],
joinDate [date/time],
category [one of 5 categories]
```

I need to add a Calculated column to this table, which will assign correct promotionPeriod based on parameters mentioned above.

It need to look for this period in another table with promotion periods, which look like this:

```
startDate, endDate [date/time]
category [one of 5 categories]
returningCustomer [TRUE/FALSE]
promotionPeriod [integer]
```

The thing is that promotion period numering is starting from 1 for each category/returningCustomer combination for date ranges during one year. It means there is for example

```
promotionPeriod = 1 for returningCustomer=TRUE of category=3 in 2016 year
```

as well as there is

```
promotionPeriod = 1 for returningCustomer=FALSE of category=3 in 2016 year
```

and

```
promotionPeriod = 1 for returningCustomer=FALSE of category=4 in 2017 year
```

and so on.

It's done that way because markting need to be able to compare dynamic in promotionPeriods year to year for every category and customer type and the start/end dates of promotion periods may vary by few days in different years.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble visualizing this. Can you create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what your tables look like and what the correct calculated column values would be?

Comment: Below you can find the screenshot of part of table with promotion periods:
![promo periods table](http://www.pl.image-share.com/ipng-553-254.html)

Customer is signing up for certain product on perticular date and can be a returning customer (bought something before). So based on sign-in date i need to look for promotional period numer for every sale.

Comment: FYI, your link's domain is blocked as porn on my work computer.

Comment: Hmmm, it's ordinary image sharing site, I guess some people use it for sharing dirty photos